# System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal not set in AuthorizationFilterAttribute

Tags: c#

I am trying to do basic authentication using attribute mapping (AuthorizationFilterAttribute) using technique shown [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1005485/restful-day-sharp-security-in-web-apis-basic)

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!_active)
            return;
        var identity = FetchHeader(actionContext);
        if (identity == null)
        {
            ChallengeAuthRequestFilter(actionContext);
            return;
        }
        var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;
        var val = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (!OnAuthorizeUser(identity.Name, identity.Password, actionContext))
        {
            ChallengeAuthRequestFilter(actionContext);
            return;
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
```

I am using this attribute on my Controller[AuthenticationController]

```
[ApiAuthenticationFilter(true)] //This is the attribute class
    [RoutePrefix("api/Authentication")]
    public class AuthenticateController : ApiController
    {
        private ITokenService _tokenService;

        public AuthenticateController() { }
        public AuthenticateController(ITokenService tokenService)
        {
            _tokenService = tokenService;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        [Route("Login")]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(User user)
        {
            if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                BasicAuthenticationIdentity identity = Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as BasicAuthenticationIdentity;
                if (identity != null)
                    return GenerateToken(identity.UserId);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

**MyQuestion**

Even though I am setting the CurrentPrincipal to genericPrincipal object and getting IsAuthenticated property as true:

```
var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;
```

and using it in my Controller to check IsAuthenticated property which is coming as false

```
if (System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Why I am getting IsAuthenticated property false in my controller, when I am getting it true in attribute class.

Please guide, what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue before and i solved this by using HttpContext.Current.User instead of System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

Below is the sample code:

```
var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
HttpContext.Current.User = genericPrincipal;
```

In your controller:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User != null && HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Hopefully this answer helps you.